# Is there a way to replace only a specific substring in java?

Tags: java, string

I am new to programming, I'm aware of basic functions in Java, but I got stuck at a problem where in I had to replace a substring with a different set of characters.

For eg, a `String str="gallbladder"`

I just want to replace the 'a' at the 1st index with an 'o', upon using

```
str.replace("a","o")
```

or

```
str.replace(str.charAt(1),"o")
```

This replaces all the 'a's with 'o's. Is there any other way to go about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace only a specific substring in Java, you can use the `replaceFirst` method or manipulate the string using the `substring` method. Here's an example using `replaceFirst`:

```java
String str = "gallbladder";
str = str.replaceFirst("allb", "o");
System.out.println(str);  // This will print "goladder"
```

Alternatively, you can achieve this using `substring` if you know the index or use `indexOf` to get the index first:

```java
String str = "gallbladder";
int index = 1; // Index of the 'a' you want to replace
str = str.substring(0, index) + "o" + str.substring(index + 1);
System.out.println(str);  // This will also print "gollbladder"
```

These methods will replace only the first occurrence of 'a' in the string.

Comment: Thank you for the input, It does help a little bit. But, is there any way where I can replace any character which is not the 1st occurrence. Eg in the word 'alabama', If i wish to replace the 'a' at the 4th index with some other character, is that possible?

Comment: Then you use the second piece of the solution. You provide the index that you want to replace and that can be done. 

You can also use StringBuilder to accomplish this.

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(str);
stringBuilder.setCharAt(indexToReplace, newChar);
String str = stringBuilder.toString();

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to replace **1st** matching substring, you can use "replaceFirst" method.

```
    String str = "gallbladder";
    str = str.replaceFirst("a", "o");
    System.out.println(str);
```

Otherwise if you want to replace different index, you can write a code like below. Lets say you want to replace 3rd(2nd index) "al" from "gallblaldd aleral"

```
    String str = "gallblaldd aleral";
    String stringToReplace = "al";
    String replaceWith = "o";
    String[]  splitStrings= str.split(stringToReplace);
    int matchingIndexToReplace = 2;
    int index = 0;
    str = "";
    for (String s : splitStrings) {
        if (index == matchingIndexToReplace) {
            str = str + s + replaceWith;
        } else if (index != matchingIndexToReplace && (index != (splitStrings.length - 1) || matchingIndexToReplace != (splitStrings.length - 1))) {
            str = str + s + stringToReplace;
        } else {
            str = str + s;
        }
        index++;
    }

    System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, I prefer the use of `replaceFirst`, which has already been demonstrated.

If, however, you need something a little more complicated, you should consider making use of a `StringBuilder`, as a, very basic, example...

```
String str = "gallbladder";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
int index = str.indexOf('a');
sb.replace(index, index, "*");
str = sb.toString();
```

This essentially acts like a mutable `String`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex approach to replace the nth occurrence of a string:

```
String replace(String str, String find, String replace, int occurrence) {
    return str.replaceFirst("((?:" + find + ".*?){" + (occurrence - 1) + "})" + find, "$1" + replace);
}
```

Basically, the replacement `$1` refers to the outer capturing group which matches any text containing the search string `n - 1` times, followed by the replacement for the final occurrence.

For brevity's sake I left out escaping, but if you don't know the contents of `find` and `replace`, you may need to wrap them in `Pattern.quote()` and `Matcher.quoteReplacement()` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I just want to replace the 'a' at the 1st index with an 'o' ..."*

Utilize the *[StringBuilder#setCharAt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt(int,char))* method.

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("gallbladder");
s.setCharAt(1, 'o');
```

If you don't know the index, you can use the *[indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))*, or *[lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String))*, methods.

```java
s.setCharAt(s.indexOf("a"), 'o');
```

Alternately, use the *[String#replaceFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))* method.
Keep in mind, the argument will be interpreted as a *[regular expression pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*.
Place the value within `\Q` and `\E`, to void any syntactic values.
Although, in this case, *"a"* is not a meta-character.

```java
String s = "gallbladder";
s = s.replaceFirst("\\Qa\\E", "o");
```

Or, conveniently use the *[Pattern#quote](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String))* method.

```java
s = s.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("a"), "o");
```